# How to get Jboss jdbc datasource node name and jms node name

Tags: jboss-eap-6, jython-2.7

I am using Jboss EAP 6.3 and I want mornitor the server healthy, now I meet a problem: I have created two data sources ("ExampleDS" and "ExampleDS2"). Is any one know how to get the jdbc datasource name with a list and also the jms name by using jmx Mbean?

And now I can get the serverName and serverState by remoteJmx.

```
def getServerState():
    serviceURL = javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:remoting-jmx://localhost:9999"))
    connector = javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, None)
    connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection()

    service = javax.management.ObjectName("jboss.as:management-root=server")
    serverName = connection.getAttribute(service,"name")
    serverState = connection.getAttribute(service,"serverState")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) (mbeans tab) to list all mbeans in a local java process. From there you can explore the JMX tree to find your jmx datasource and jms names.

Your Datasources will be found at:

```
jboss.as:subsystem=datasources,data-source=ExampleDS
```

By JMS do you mean a JMS messaging Queue name? The JMX name will be

```
jboss.as:subsystem=messaging,hornetq-server=default,jms-queue=ExampleQueueName
```